# International UTF-32 strings output to console in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse-cdt, utf-32

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    const wchar_t *str = L"\u041F\u043E\u0440\u044F\u0434\u043E\u043A";
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
    std::wcout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Here's a piece of code that outputs a russian phrase in UTF-32 wchar_t string as:

- The correct one: **Порядок** when run from UTF-8 gnome terminal in Ubuntu 11.10
- РџРѕСЂСЏРґРѕРє in Eclipse in the test run as above
- 45=B8D8:0B>@ in Eclipse in a real program (where I don't even know who does what and where, but I suppose someone does mess with locales)
- ??????? if I don't call locale
- str is shown as Details:0x400960 L"\320\237\320\276\321\200\321\217\320\264\320\276\320\272" in Eclipse Watch window
- is shown as ASCII only *byte chars* in Eclipse memory window (and there's no way to specify that this is UTF-32 string)

I believe this is a misconfiguration in either eclipse console or the program, because, for example, other people that just run my code in Eclipse they do [see](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/7161984?cid=7163441) the correct [output](http://i27.fastpic.ru/big/2011/1222/27/d347892b3d2750e14ab2717a55122727.png).

Could someone shed a light on this confusion? What is the correct way to setup all the pieces (OS, gcc, terminal, Eclipse, sources...) to output international symbols that are stored in UTF-32 wchar_t strings?

And as a side note, why should I still care about all this when we have UTF-32 and that should be enough to know what is inside...

Comment: You can try updating your "Run configurations">Common>Encoding & select the right encoding ("UTF8" seems to do the trick in my case) Some details [here](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/)

Comment: Doesn't solve all the problems (actually haven't even tried the solution yet) but looks like a good one.

Comment: Thats quite all right! Please do give it a shot though. Similar to encoding option under "Run configurations" there is one under "Debug configurations">Common>Encoding as well. Maybe you can set both configurations appropriately & see if it helps

Comment: Yes, this helps with small test program as above, but not with the real one. Will have to find out what's wrong there. Still Eclipse does not understand UTF-32 in its memory/watch; but maybe because of older version (helios).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be that other code changed locale.